# Need SELECT query help for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I want data from the order table which contain products related to category ID(80). This is the category ID.
And want data From: 2012-11-17 to 2015-9-15.
Data I needed (Name, email, shipping address, phone number.)

Comment: from 15 sept 2015  to till date?

Comment: I looked into these three table "sales_flat_order" , "sales_flat_order_address", "sales_flat_order_item" for joining.

But not getting perfect data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this code on your root folder :

```
  <?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$catId = 46; 
$outputFile = 'var/myfile.csv'; //csv file location
$write = fopen($outputFile, 'w');
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('12/07/2015')); // eg. 12/07/2015
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('12/07/2017'));

$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))
                    ->load();
foreach($orderCollection as $order)
{
    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order->getId());
    $orderIncrementId= $order->getIncrementId();
    $orderObj = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
    $orderItems = $orderObj->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach($orderItems as $i):
        $productId = $i->getProductId(); // get product id from each line item
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    endforeach;

    if (in_array($catId, $categoryIds))
    {
        // put your logic here for get info 
        $data = array($order->getId(),$order->getCustomerName(),$order->getCustomerEmail());
        fputcsv($write, $data);

    }
}
fclose($write);
?>
```

**[Edit]**

Here is very simple code for save data in csv.

```
<?php 
       $outputFile = 'var/myfile.csv'; //csv file location
       $mage_csv = new Varien_File_Csv(); //mage CSV   
       $mainArray = array();
       foreach($ordercol as $order)
       {
         $data = array();
         $data['id'] = $order->getId();
         $data['name'] = $order->getCustomerName();
         $data['email'] = $order->getCustomerEmail();
          $mainArray[] =  $data;
       }
       $titles = array('id','name','email'); // for set the field name
       array_unshift($mainArray,$titles);
       $mage_csv->saveData($outputFile, $mainArray);

       ?>
```

Comment: Can you please put code where I can generate csv file. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Ravi updated the code for csv

Comment: Only one record I got in csv file where I found 336 data. And trying to debug but not getting. Also need column field name. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Ravi I'm getting all record in my csv and  updated the code for save date in csv you can customize it according to your need thanks

Comment: Thank you Arunendra sir, I debug the code actually it's not working in IF condition for cat_id. But fine I will manage it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these 3 steps:

1. Get order collection based on date filter.
2. In Foreach loop, load order and get Items of order.
3. Get category of Items and place a condition if category Id is 80 then get order Id, customer name, customer email.